# Lazy regex operator doesn't work in bash

Tags: regex, bash, expr

```
echo "$(expr "title: Purple Haze       artist: Jimi Hendrix" : 'title:\s*\(.*\?\)\s*artist.*' )"
```

prints

```
Purple Haze
```

With the trailing whitespace, even though I am using the `?` lazy operator.

I've tested this on https://regex101.com/ and it works as expected, what's different about bash?

Comment: Does not print anything for me (tried with MacOS 10.6)

Comment: DONT escape the `?` !!!

Comment: @Enissay No, these are BRE, not ERE: `?` matches a question mark, `\?` is the zero-or-one operator.

Comment: @Gilles oh, my bad... Good to know <3

Comment: @JakubM. Sorry I should have added, I am on Debian and `expr` on linux is a bit more powerful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't using bash's regexp matching, you're using `expr`. `expr` does not have a “`?` lazy operator”, it only implements [basic regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (with a few extensions in the Linux version, such as `\s` for whitespace, but that doesn't include Perl-like lazy operators). (Neither does bash, for that matter.)

If you don't want `.*` to include trailing space, specify that it must end with a character that isn't a space:

```
'title:\s*\(.*\S\)\s*artist.*'
```

Comment: Perhaps also mention that `expr` should generally be avoided. If you are using Bash, it already has built-in replacements for everything `expr` does, which are often also more readable, efficient, versatile, and robust.

Answer (score 2):

[As Gilles points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27767015/2088135), you're not using bash regular expressions. To do so, you could use the regex match operator `=~` like this:

```
re='title:[[:space:]]*(.*[^[:space:]])[[:space:]]*artist.*'
details='title: Purple Haze       artist: Jimi Hendrix'
[[ $details =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Rather than using a lazy match, this uses a non-space character at the end of the capture group, so the trailing space is removed. The first capture group is stored in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`.

At the expense of cross-platform portability, it is also possible to use the shorthand `\s` and `\S` instead of `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`:

```
re='title:\s*(.*\S)\s*artist.*'
```